# Android detects SIM change – gmail synchronized messages deleted?

Tags: security, gmail, sim-card

After gmail detects SIM change – it asks to renew login to gmail account.

This is a very good security action. But does it maybe also clear synchronized messages (that have been downloaded before SIM change)?